# Checking for set existence in YACC

Tags: parsing, yacc

I am trying to write rules in YACC (`.y` file). I want to make sure that certain tokens occur together or they don't appear at all.

I tried writing this :

```
rule_pilot : NULL | rule_pilot rule
rule : A | B | C | D | E | F
```

Some valid strings are:

- A**BCD**
- A**C**E**DB**
- F**CD**A**B**
- AE
- FA
- EFA

As shown in example valid strings, what i want is **all `B`, `C` and `D` come in the string or none of them come in the string**. But rule_pilot can't ensure that. It will also accept strings like ABC, B etc.

How should I write `rule_pilot` so that it fulfills the above mentioned criteria?

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this would be to do this elsewhere: in the lexer or as part of a semantic check (i.e., after parsing). If you wanted to do this in the parser you'd need inifinite-token lookahead and yacc only has one-token lookahead.

Comment: Exactly. A CFG is the last tool you should pick for this task.